# Is there a tool to watch a remote Git repository on Ubuntu and do popup notifications when commits are made?

Tags: git, ubuntu, notifications, commit

I would like to have popup notifications when people make commits to repositories that I am watching. Not hosted on any particular site like github or anything, so the ability to just add the repository URL to a list of watched repositories would be needed. And as the title says, this is for Ubuntu, but cross platform is welcome!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

And thus, [git-notify](https://github.com/jakeonrails/git-notify) was born!

This little bash script will watch your origin/master for updates every 60 seconds and uses notify-send to alert you of new commits.

Answer (score 1):

If the repo isn't hosted locally (ie other people pushing to a repository hosted on your hard drive), you're probably going to need some form of polling, which is going to be slow and/or painful.  Look at @Abizern's idea instead and create post-receive hooks in the repositories that send out emails whenever someone pushes to them.  At my company we use the stock hook scripts included in the git suite, they're pretty fantastic and useful.

Comment: I figured as much. Thought about writing some quick script to iterate over a list of repos and somehow check them for updates, and then use the notification API in ubuntu, but thought I'd check here first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at writing post-commit hooks?

Comment: No, but just because I'm looking for something that could watch repos that I don't have control over. Like for instance, a Repo hosted on Github or Assembla or something.