# How can I add versioning to concourse pipeline?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, pipeline, concourse-pipeline

After issuing a `fly` command to a Concourse pipeline, I would like to version this new pipeline.

I have tried maintain a separate `version' file on GIT repo.

But my requirement is to display this version on pipeline job name.

[Please see the image where a version has to be appended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EiiF.png)

Adding more details:

I am looking at facility in GIT to watch for commits on a particular folder (say `xyz`). I got something similar the below:

> [Is there a tool to watch a remote Git repository on Ubuntu and do popup notifications when commits are made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082001/is-there-a-tool-to-watch-a-remote-git-repository-on-ubuntu-and-do-popup-notificat)
>
> https://github.com/jakeonrails/git-notify

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The other answer for this question is achieved with below code:

```
  plan:
  - get: test-version-resource
  - task: send-version
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: gliderlabs/alpine
          tag: latest 
      inputs:
      - name: test-version-resource
      run:
        path: /bin/sh
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          ls -la test-version-resource
```

Comment: If anyone tries this out, please share if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by placing a placeholder for `pipeline_version` in pipeline file for the job name.

```
- name: set_env_test_((pipeline_version))
```

In the parameters file 'pipeline_version' is populated as below:

```
pipeline_version: 1.0.0
```

[Click here to see what was achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktVNR.png)